# Custom serialize and deserialize to create JSON

Tags: java, json, groovy

I have a class with 2 values: val1 and val2. I am sending val1 to register (create) API and val2 is auto filled by API itself. I do not want to send val2 while calling create API and that API is not designed for handling unwanted values.

In short I want to ignore val2 while I call create API but I want it while I call get API.

The code that I have right now creates JSON including both the values assigning null to val2. This causes that API to throw an exception.

Is there any easy way of doing it (java /groovy)?

Comment: Well show us your code and then show us what you want want the new code to produce

Comment: It would be good to show the full exception here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any easy way of doing it (java /groovy)?

Not 100% sure I'm understanding your need.  I believe it depends on what json de/serializer you are using.  For example, using Jackson we do:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeName("account")
public class Account {
```

I believe this allows us to load in objects with a ton of extra json fields into objects without corresponding java fields.  To quote from the [javadocs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html):

> Property that defines whether it is ok to just ignore any unrecognized properties during deserialization.  If true, all properties that are unrecognized -- that is, there are no setters or creators that accept them -- are ignored without warnings (although handlers for unknown properties, if any, will still be called) without exception.